# Counting the number of comments that have no reply in Adobe Acrobat Pro XI

Tags: windows-7, adobe-acrobat

Is there any way to count the number of comments that have no reply in Adobe Acrobat Pro XI?

I use Adobe Acrobat Pro XI with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to count the number of comments that have no reply in Adobe Acrobat Pro XI.